# Working with ChartObjects

Tags: vba, excel

I have a quick question regarding modifying the axes of a ChartObject with VBA in Excel.

I have the following code, which modifies the min/max value of an axis based on the data it is charting:

```
Worksheets("DurationByDate").ChartObjects("DurationByDateChart").Activate
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
    .MinimumScale = iDurMin - 2
    .MaximumScale = iDurMax + 2
End With
```

This works well, but I don't like "activating" objects if I don't need to.

So I tried the following code:

```
With Worksheets("DurationByDate").ChartObjects("DurationByDateChart") _
.Axes(xlValue)
    .MinimumScale = iDurMin - 2
    .MaximumScale = iDurMax + 2
End With
```

This code throws an error:

> Run-time Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Does anyone know why it seems like the chart needs to be active in order to adjust the axes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.Chart` near the end of your `With` statement:

```
With Worksheets("DurationByDate").ChartObjects("DurationByDateChart").Chart.Axes(xlValue)
```